# SAML 2.0 Browser/Post Profile Single Sign-On to classic asp web site

Tags: asp-classic, saml

I'm new in SAML 2.0 Single Sign-On implementation. My client needs to provide them a Single Sign-On on my classic asp website by SAML 2.0 Browser/Post Profile. My client will provide me the xml meta data and certificate but I don't know the solution that I'll provide with them.

Could it be possible to do SAML 2.0 Browser/Post Profile with my classic asp site? What are the task and solution the I need to do?

Please advise. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly possible - although you could have some challenges in a classic ASP environment.  Do you know if you will be acting as an Identity Provider or Service Provider in this SSO setup?  From the sounds of it, I would expect Service Provider - in which case you will need to parse & validate incoming SAML Assertions, and also possibly send SAML AuthnRequests to the IdP.  The metadata your partner provides will guide you on what protocols/URL's/certificates they will be using.

To handle the SAML protocol, you could re-invent the wheel by writing your own code in ASP.  Of course that would be time consuming and risky, it would be simpler if you used a proven solution.  There may be some but I'm not aware of any free/open source ASP implementations, so you might want to consider a commercial solution like Component Space (http://www.componentspace.com/ - although it will require .NET), or something like PingFederate Express which offers a simple IIS plug-in (http://www.pingidentity.com/our-solutions/pingfederate-express.cfm).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It appears that the certificate is under X509Certificate base on there meta data. If I will not using some commercial solution what will be the steps that needs to be implemented? I've seen some example though it is implemented in .net http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DotNetSamlPost.aspx?display=Print. What will be the purpose of the meta data and certificate if I will use this approach? Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: Metadata tells you what parts of the SAML 2.0 protocol your partner supports, along with the URL's of their "end points" (basically their responders that will interpret SAML requests / responses).  The certificate contained within is likely the public verification certificate that corresponds to the private key used to digitally sign their SAML Assertions.  It is critical that you validate the signature on your end - and hopefully also do revocation checking - otherwise it opens up the door to hackers spoofing an assertion.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your explanation. However, Does it mean that the login authentication of my classic asp site will be eliminated? and if my client logged-in using there site and click a link that points to our site it will automatically authenticated. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: It could, yes.  Many SAML SSO integrations at the SP just redirect to the IdP to authenticate all users.  You don't need to though - you could have an intermediate login page that has the same login form you do today, with simply a link to authenticate via the IdP instead.  A user at the IdP would indeed be able to follow a link to send an "unsolicited" authentication response (containing a SAML Assertion) to authenticate to your SP.  Whether you just let everyone in or not is up to you; it's entirely based on how you map to local accounts from the info presented in the SAML Assertion.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the .NET SAML handling classes in a COM library. I have a similar project and this looks like what I'll have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Scott T has a point. PFE is one possibility if your client also uses PF. If you were to utilize PingFederate (PF) you could either use our (I work for PI.com) IIS plug-in or Agentless Integration Kit (we have quite a few supporting classic ASP apps this way today) to quickly add SAML support to your app. The use of PF would allow you to support SAML 2.0/1.1/1.0/WS-Fed/OpenID (and others) simultaneously with a single, simple, secure integration to your application.  Check out http://www.pingidentity.com/partners/SaaS-Partner-Program.cfm for more info.

--Ian